# Is my proof correct? (Also formally)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, summation

**Hello dear community!**

I just worked on a problem in my discrete mathematics text book and wondered if my approach to a specific exercise is correct. There are no solutions to it, that's the reason I am asking here.

**Problem:**

$\forall m\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $m$ is odd, $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(n+k)$ is divisible by $m$.

**Proof:**

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(n+k)$  Then we depict the sum in expanded form:
$$\begin{align}
S_n &= n + (n+1)+(n+2)+\cdots+(n+m-1) \\
S_n - mn &= 0 + 1 + 2+\cdots+(m-1) \\
S_n - mn &= \frac{(m-1)((m-1)+1)}{2} \\
S_n &= \frac{m(m-1)}{2}+mn\\
\end{align}$$

In the second step we subtract by $mn$ because $n$ is included $0$ to $m-1=m$ times in the terms of the sum. Then in the third step can use the forumula for the sum of the first n intergers: $0 + 1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Now we need to show that $S_n$ is divisible by $m$. By definition of odd, $m=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. We continue with the equation:
$$\begin{align}
S_n &= \frac{m(m-1)}{2}+mn\\
S_n &= m\left(\frac{(m-1)}{2}+n\right)\\
S_n &= m\left(\frac{((2k+1)-1)}{2}+n\right)\\
S_n &= m\left(k+n\right)\\
\end{align}$$

We used the definition for odd integers and substituted the $m$ within the big parantheses with $2k+1$ where k is any integer. Now because $k$ and $n$ are integers and because sums of integers are integers, $k+n$ is an also an integer. Let $q=k+n$. Then $S_n=mq$ and hence  $S_n$ is divisible by $m$ by definition of divisiblity. That is what was to show. q.e.d.

[End Proof]

Is this proof formally correct? Are there any logical flaws? Is the order correct? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Yes. No. Yes. You are welcome.

Comment: Yes, your proof is formally correct, but you could also write
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (n+k) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} n + \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} k = mn + \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} k = mn + \frac{m(m-1)}{2} = m \left ( n + \frac{m-1}{2} \right )$$
And conclude for $m$ odd, $\frac{m-1}{2}$ is an integer and so is $n + \frac{m-1}{2}$, making the same argument shorter
Without having to "expand" the sum.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @AlexR: I didn't spot that, but it's a very nice way to deduce the answer. Even better, I understand it :)

Comment: Your proof is fine - except that I personally do not like *at all* the occurance of ellipsis ("$\ldots$") in a proof that is supposed to be *formal*. So the answer may depend on what level of formality is expected (or cf. AlexR's method without ellipsis) -  But I don't want to imply that using "$\ldots$" (at least at first or while looking for a formal proof) is to be banned.